# Check a list of checkboxes if input value matches one of the values in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects (array1) that I am looping through and rendering in a form as a series of inputs where type="checkbox". I am setting the input value to the object.id, and the input name to the object.name.

I then have a second array (array2), which is just an array of values. I need to compare array1 to array2, and if the value for that given input matches one of the values in array2, then set checked="true." If not, then do not check. It's basically auto-checking any inputs that already have a value that exists in array2.

```
let array1 = [
{id: 28, name: "Action"}, 
{id: 35, name: "Comedy"},
{id: 80, name: "Crime"},
{id: 99, name: "Documentary"}
{id: 18, name: "Drama"}
{id: 10751, name: "Family"}
]

let array2 = [1, 65, 28, 12, 18]
```

Here's what I have for my loop:

```
for(let i in array2) {
   for(let j in array1) {
      if(array2[i] == array1[j].id) {
          return (
          <div>
             <label>name here</label>
             <input type="checkbox" id={array1[j].id} value={array1[j].id} name={array1[j].name} checked='true'/>
          </div>
          )
    }
      if(array2[i] != array1[j].id) {
           return (
           <div>
               <label>name here</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id={array1[j].id} value={array1[j].id} name={array1[j].name}/>
           </div>
          )
   }
```

Obviously this isn't working and sorry if my current code seems stupid. I've been at this for a while and I'm at a complete loss on how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `array1` to the checkbox inputs and do a simple check that `array2` includes the `id` property from elements in `array1`.

```
{array1.map(({ id, name }) => (
  <label key={id}>
    {name}
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value={id}
      name={name}
      defaultChecked={array2.includes(id)}
    />
  </label>
))}
```

[image: Edit check-a-list-of-checkboxes-if-input-value-matches-one-of-the-values-in-different]

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this via [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
return array1.map(({id, name}) => (
  <input
    key={id}
    name={name}
    checked={array2.includes(id)}
  />
))
```